# Is it possible to skip to application install step from prerequisites dialog to execute setup.exe by making Visual Studio Installer Project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm trying to build VS Installer Project and to execute setup.exe after building in the project.

I make the prerequisites which is VC++ 2015 distributable(x86)(Option is "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application"), build it and test to execute setup.exe.

The setup.exe is good working. But if VC++ 2015 distributable(x86) is already installed, It can not skip to next step(installing my application) when I cancel prerequisites dialog.

Is it possible to skip to next step when canceling prerequisites dialog if i execute setup.exe?

I want to work this installer that is just openning to next step install dialog If I click cancel button in prerequisites dialog...

1. Excute setup.exe

[image: Excute setup.exe]

2. Click close(cancel) button in the prerequisite dialog

[image: Click close button in dialog]

3. Then display error message box. I can not pass to next install step

[image: Then display error message box. Can not pass to next install step]

Comment: If the VC++ redist is already installed it's supposed to notice, skip it and carry on. If that is not happening, please describe what you are seeing.

Comment: I wrote and posted it what I saw the situation. If I click cancel button in the prerequisite dialog, I just want to continue to the next step which is installing my application

Comment: As I said before, if the same VC++ runtime is already installed it will not attempt to install it again - there may be something wrong with your system. This is not how prerequisites normally work. Either that, or the version that's already installed is different to the prerequisite version, so it's doing an update of it, or installing an alternate side by side version. There is not enough info to say what's going on or if. Also, canceling the prereq install cancels the entire install. Just install the MSI to skip prereqs.